# how would i create a file output stream in c like stdout?

Tags: c, stream, io, streaming, stdout

if printf uses stdout but how would i write a print function using my own output stream?  i want to handle this stream with a OO-like structure but i can do that myself.  is this possible?  this for learning.

would something like this work - i didnt test this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

FILE* stdout2 = NULL;

int init() {
    stdout2 = fopen("stdout.txt", "w");
    if (!stdout2) return -1;
    return 1;
}

void print(char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list fmt_args;
    va_start(fmt_args, fmt);
    char buffer[300];
    vsprintf(buffer, fmt, fmt_args);
    fprintf(stdout2, buffer);
    fflush(stdout2);
}

void close() {
    fclose(stdout2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    init();
    print("hi"); // to console?
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

how would i get printf(char*, ...) print to the console?  would i have to read the file in the same function?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing... Your code, although ugly :-), is fine in as much as it works.  I would highly recommend return 0 on success of functions which return int type (instead of 1) ... what do you want to do with print("hi")? do you want to print it to console AND to a file?  If so that can be done quite a bit more efficiently than what you are doing.

Answer (score 8):

Try use `fdopen` (see [The GNU C Library: Descriptors and Streams](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Descriptors-and-Streams.html#Descriptors-and-Streams)).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int filedes = 3; // New descriptor
  FILE *stream = fdopen (filedes, "w");
  fprintf (stream, "hello, world!\n");
  fprintf (stream, "goodbye, world!\n");
  fclose (stream);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile with gcc as below, where `3` is the same as defined in `filedes`.

```
gcc -o teststream teststream.c && ./teststream 3> afile.txt && cat afile.txt
```

The result:

```
hello, world!
goodbye, world!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to FILE*'s with [fprintf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), which will have the same semantics as printf.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    init();
    fprintf(stdout2,"hi"); // will print to file
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats mostly correct. You should use functions that use length parameters though for security/overflow purposes. Secondly, the console (i.e. stdout) is simply a file descriptor with an id of 0, stderr is 1. You can open file descriptors with `fdopen`

```
int main(){
    stdout2 = fdopen(stdout, "w");
    print("Hello World"); //This will print to console
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok i understand that but when i use the print function it is going to the file which is good but does printf use another file like stdin to put it on the console?

Comment: fdopen returns a FILE* see: http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/fdopen.3.asp . That means that you can use a FILE* to write to the console. If you are asking how printf itself is implemented, I believe it uses basic functions like `putchar`

Answer (score 0):

If, inside `init`, you assign `stdout` to your own variable, the output will be to the console

```
void init() {
    stdout2 = stdout;
    if (!stdout2) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: stdout is usually #defined to the fd number: 0 meaning that you have to fdopen it first

Comment: @chacham15: see 7.16.1/3 in the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n869/n869.txt.gz). `stdout` is an "expression of type *pointer to FILE*"; there is no reference about it being macro or references to "fd"s or even "file descriptor"s

Comment: ah, well i am used to pre c90 standards (usually for the sake of portability)

Comment: @chacham15: You are thinking of `STDOUT_FILENO` which is always defined to 0.  There *was* no pre-c90 standard other than K&R first edition, in which `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are "file pointers".

Comment: just tested this on my system, using gcc3 with cygwin stdout is #defined to 0

Comment: @chacham15 actually STDOUT_FILENO is 1; STDIN_FILENO is 0; and for completeness STDERR_FILENO is 2

Comment: huh? im lost then, anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you print to both the specified file and outstream (terminal). You have to specify the file pointer, and the rest is the usual format of printf.

```
void my_printf(FILE * fileptr, const char * string, ...){

    char inBuf[100];

    va_list args;

    va_start(args, string);

    vsprintf(inBuf, string, args);

    fprintf(fileptr, inBuf);
    printf("%s", inBuf);

    va_end(args);

}
```

Example:

```
I/P:
my_printf( `file pointer`, "Hello World, today is \"%d\"th June", 10);

O/P:
Hello World, today is "10"th June
```